# Pointing same domain to different app service in Azure

Tags: azure, dns, azure-mobile-services, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am using Azure App Service to host my NodeExpress application, I am right now stuck at a very strange requirement.

I have 2 different azure app services.
1) myApp
2) sampleApp

I have a domain pointed at myApp. (Added hostname www.myapp.com)
now I want to delete myApp and shift my hostname (www.myapp.com) to sampleApp.

now my Question is,

will it change my IP Address? (This I think it would because I haven't bought any static IP)

if my app service pointing IP is changed, will I have to do anything with the domain DNS manager to move www.myapp.com in hostnames of sample app?

I don't have access to DNS Manager because client has it. I have to tell client to add CNAME to verify domain ownership. I want to point this domain to different app service without adding delay of asking my client to change its cname to verify domain ownership.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to register the new CNAME from your web application in the DNS server before adding it to Azure App Service. Right now you have something like this:

```
www.mydomain.com CNAME mynodeapp1.azurewebsites.net
```

First, change it to your new application address:

```
www.mydomain.com CNAME mynewnodeapp1.azurewebsites.net
```

And then add the custom domain to your new web application.

App Service does provide you with a public IP address, but it's not guaranteed to remain the same, although it's unlikely to change. Said that, as long as you keep using CNAME, you shouldn't have any problems. If you delete the original app and recreate using the same Azure FQDN, then you don't need to change anything on customer DNS settings, Azure will be able to verify the domain successfully in this case.

Comment: I just deleted my old app, but it's not letting me create one again. It just says not available. while adding the hostname to a new app-service deployment, I need to re-verify domain ownership using CNAME, which is kind of impossible, because I don't have access to domain hosting panel.

Comment: Usually, takes a few minutes before you can create a new web app with the same name. If you recreate the web app using the same name, the DNS settings will be already in place, so you shouldn't need to change anything on the customer side.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually migrate the domainname without downtime by using a verify record. Just create the record:

```
awverify.www.mydomain.com CNAME mynewnodeapp1.azurewebsites.net
```

That will enable you to add the hostname `www.domain.com` to sampleApp in azure (and add an SSL binding).

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-migrate-domain